# Error in as.vector(x, "character") : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, dashdb

//i had shared a piece of code where i am getting the error.
here i want to pass the date range and get the data from the query in my data frame

```
    output$DateRange <- renderText(
            if(USER$Logged==TRUE){
```

//getting the input date ranges from here

```
validate(
                need(as.character(Sys.Date()) >= input$dates[1], 
"Start Date should be less than or equal to Current Date"
                )
              )


 validate(
  need(input$dates[2] <= as.character(Sys.Date())  && input$dates[2] >= input$dates[1], "End Date should be greater than Start date and less than Current Date"
            ))



    })

  //i am passing date range from here in my query but i am getting a error while passing datesetFirst and datesetSecond 
    datesetFirst <- reactive(input$dates[1])
    datesetSecond <- reactive(input$dates[2])

    if (!is.null(datesetFirst) && !is.null(datesetSecond))
    {
```

// this is the query i want to execute after passing the date range from here i want to get the data on the basis of input range

```
resultset =paste("SELECT SET2.AREA_NAME,SET2.PROD_NM,
      SET2.TherapeuticClass,set2.TOTAL,
      ROUND(((set2.TOTAL/SET3.TOTAL)*100),2) as SHARE
      FROM (select retail_store_area_wise.area_name AS AREA_NAME,
      set1.PROD_NM AS PROD_NM,sum(set1.TOTAL) AS TOTAL,
      set1.TH_CLASS_1 AS TH_1,
      set1.TH_CLASS_2 AS TH_2,
      set1.TH_CLASS_3 AS TH_3,
      set1.TH_CLASS_4 AS TH_4,
      CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_1, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_2),','),CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_3, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_4) ) as TherapeuticClass
      from
      (select  
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 as TH_CLASS_4,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 as TH_CLASS_3,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 as TH_CLASS_2,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 as TH_CLASS_1,
      retail_store_prod.store_id as store_id ,
      retail_store.str_nm,
      retail_Str_sales_detail.prod_nm  as PROD_NM,
      round(sum (retail_Str_sales_detail.total),2) AS TOTAL
      from
      retail_str_sales_detail ,
      retail_store_prod,retail_store
      where 
      retail_store_prod.prod_nm = retail_str_sales_detail.prod_nm and 
      retail_store_prod.store_id=retail_str_sales_detail.store_id  and 
      retail_store.store_id = retail_store_prod.store_id AND
      retail_str_sales_detail.SALE_DATE BETWEEN  //while passing the date range here i am getting the error**'",datesetFirst,"'** AND **'",datesetSecond,"'**

      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 != 'NULL'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 != 'NULL'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 != 'NULL'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 != 'NULL' 
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 != ''
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 != ''
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 != ''
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 != ''
      GROUP BY 
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 ,
      retail_Str_sales_detail.prod_nm ,retail_store.str_nm,
      retail_store_prod.store_id
      order by retail_Str_sales_detail.prod_nm,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 ,retail_store.str_nm,
      round(sum (retail_Str_sales_detail.total),2) desc) as set1, retail_store_area_wise
      where set1.store_id = retail_store_area_wise.store_id
      group by set1.PROD_NM,
      set1.TH_CLASS_1,
      set1.TH_CLASS_2,
      set1.TH_CLASS_3,
      set1.TH_CLASS_4,
      retail_store_area_wise.area_name,CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_1, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_2),','),CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_3, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_4) )
      order by retail_store_area_wise.area_name,set1.PROD_NM) as SET2
      FULL OUTER JOIN 
      (select retail_store_area_wise.area_name AS AREA_NAME,sum(set1.TOTAL) AS TOTAL,
      set1.TH_CLASS_1 AS TH_1,
      set1.TH_CLASS_2 AS TH_2,
      set1.TH_CLASS_3 AS TH_3,
      set1.TH_CLASS_4 AS TH_4,
      CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_1, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_2),','),CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_3, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_4) ) as TherapeuticClass
      from
      (select  
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 as TH_CLASS_4,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 as TH_CLASS_3,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 as TH_CLASS_2,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 as TH_CLASS_1,
      retail_store_prod.store_id as store_id ,
      retail_store.str_nm,
      retail_Str_sales_detail.prod_nm  as PROD_NM,
      round(sum (retail_Str_sales_detail.total),2) AS TOTAL
      from
      retail_str_sales_detail ,
      retail_store_prod,retail_store
      where 
      retail_store_prod.prod_nm = retail_str_sales_detail.prod_nm and 
      retail_store_prod.store_id=retail_str_sales_detail.store_id  and 
      retail_store.store_id = retail_store_prod.store_id AND
      retail_str_sales_detail.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '",datesetFirst,"' AND '",datesetSecond,"'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 != 'NULL'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 != 'NULL'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 != 'NULL'
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 != 'NULL' 
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 != ''
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 != ''
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 != ''
      AND retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 != ''
      GROUP BY 
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 ,
      retail_Str_sales_detail.prod_nm ,retail_store.str_nm,
      retail_store_prod.store_id
      order by retail_Str_sales_detail.prod_nm,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_4 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_3 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_2 ,
      retail_store_prod.TH_CLASS_1 ,retail_store.str_nm,
      round(sum (retail_Str_sales_detail.total),2) desc) as set1, retail_store_area_wise
      where set1.store_id = retail_store_area_wise.store_id group by 
      set1.TH_CLASS_1,
      set1.TH_CLASS_2,
      set1.TH_CLASS_3,
      set1.TH_CLASS_4,
      retail_store_area_wise.area_name,
      CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_1, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_2),','),CONCAT(CONCAT( set1.TH_CLASS_3, ','),set1.TH_CLASS_4) )
      order by retail_store_area_wise.area_name) AS SET3
      ON SET3.AREA_NAME= SET2.AREA_NAME AND
      SET3.TH_1= SET2.TH_1 AND
      SET3.TH_2 = SET2.TH_2 AND 
      SET3.TH_3 = SET2.TH_3 AND
      SET3.TH_4 = SET2.TH_4");
          querytherapeutic1= reactive({dbGetQuery(conn,resultset)})
          biztherapeuticproduct1= data.frame(
            Area= querytherapeutic1$AREA_NAME,
            THERAPEUTIC_CLASS= querytherapeutic1$THERAPEUTICCLASS,
            Market_Share= as.numeric(as.character(querytherapeutic1$SHARE)),
            Product= querytherapeutic1$PROD_NM,
            Total = as.numeric(as.character(querytherapeutic1$TOTAL)),  
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
          )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message ist from this part of the code

```
datesetFirst <- reactive(input$dates[1])
    datesetSecond <- reactive(input$dates[2])

    if (!is.null(datesetFirst) && !is.null(datesetSecond))
```

reactive returns a function not a value so you need to change your code to this

```
datesetFirst <- reactive(input$dates[1])
    datesetSecond <- reactive(input$dates[2])

    if (!is.null(datesetFirst()) && !is.null(datesetSecond()))
```

and of course in the query aswell

```
"retail_str_sales_detail.SALE_DATE BETWEEN '",datesetFirst(),"' AND '",datesetSecond(),"'
```

Comment: still it is not giving me a data what i need

Comment: You have the same problem with querytherapeutic1. It is very hard from the code you have posted to understand why you want to use reactive in these cases. I would try once removing the capsuling in reactive and maby put the whole block in an eventReactive. but first try to remove the reactive.

Comment: i dont need a reactive at all i only want to pass a date range in my query to execute

Comment: Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.) i get this error on removal of reactive

Comment: please include you whole server function or the whole rendertext as one block and I will look into it

Comment: thanks berlin but i got the answer there was a silly mistake in my code that's my bad

Comment: I flagged this question to close it, since there's a lot of code to sift through, it's incomplete as of the comments, and the problem seems to have stemmed from something noone will ever find out anymore as per the lastmost comment. OP has vanished into the abyss.